# How to inherit module in GWT for AppEngine SystemProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

When testing for dev or production mode on the client side of a GWT project, as in this line:

```
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
                SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production)
```

I get this error:

> No source code is available for type
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty; did you forget to
>   inherit a required module?

Can I do this on the client side?  If so, how can I inherit the proper module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter says, you will not be able to use that class in your GWT code directly. However, this is a perfect use case for using [this technique](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page.html).

Answer (score 3):

No, `com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty` is available only on the server side. On the client side you can only use classes which are in your GWT module directories or added to the source path: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules